# TextView shrinks TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-tablelayout

I want to create a simple flag game. You are given the country name and you must then guess the correct flag. On my play screen, i have a TextView and a TableLayout with 4 images in 2 rows. These images are the same dimension.

The problem is: The TextView "shrinks" the second TableRow, so that the images no longer are equally big. If I remove the TextView, everything is fine.

I tried to debug in Hierachy Viewer, which told me that the property mMeasuredHeight of the second TableRow had a value of a very high value (16777526)

My play activity xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp"
    tools:context=".PlayTimeModeActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFlagName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TableRow>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivFlag1"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cdFlag1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivFlag2"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cdFlag2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivFlag3"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cdFlag3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivFlag4"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cdFlag4" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do you need additional info?

I wonder if this layout of images can be done better?

Edit:
The images are pretty high resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Make the root of your layout (`LinearLayout`) have the following attributes `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Set your `TableLayout` to have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. This will make it take up any remaining space on the screen after the text has been placed, rather than squashing the Hello text.

For each `TableRow` add `android:layout_weight="1"`. This will make each row take up an even amount of space in the `TableLayout`.

For each `ImageView` in the table, set `android:layout_weight="1"`. Again, this will set an even amount of space for each of your flags.

The flag should scale accordingly. If the scaling isn't correct, try different values in the `ImageView` for `android:scaleType`.